# What is the best way to do a very large and repetitive task?

Tags: performance, audio, python-3.6

I need to get the duration of 18000+ audios, using the `audioread` library for each audio takes about 300ms, ie at least 25~30 minutes of processing.

Using a `Queue` and`Process` system, using all available cores of my processor, I can lower the processing average of each audio to 70ms, but it will still take 21 minutes, how can I improve this? I would like to be able to read all the audios in at least 5 minutes, remembering that I have no competition on the machine, it will only run my software, so I can consume all the resources.

Code of function read the duration:

```
def get_duration(q, au):
    while not q.empty():
        index = q.get()
        with audioread.audio_open(au[index]['absolute_path']) as f:
            au[index]['duration'] = f.duration * 1000
```

Code to create the Processes:

```
for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
    pr = Process(target=get_duration, args=(queue, audios, ))
    pr.daemon = True
    pr.start()
```

In my code there is only one `Queue` with some `Process`, and I use `Manager` to edit the objects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203411/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-caresia-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-very-large).

Comment: Are you open to using command line tools like `SoX` and `parallel`?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Yes, since it will be embedded

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a complied solution to speed up your script. Pythons threading still leaves room for improvement.

Try a compiled language.

If you still want python, separate as many functions to different threads as your system supports. use `threading.thread`.

Also see [this wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops)  for info on efficient loops in python. The gist of the story is that for loops incur overhead.